# Drop Down Menu opens sometimes wrong link

Tags: html

I've got a simple drop down menu like this:

```
<nav>
 <ul class="nav">
    <li class="topmenu"> <a href="#">Grp 1</a>  
    <ul id="firstul">


        <li class="submenu"><a href="https://www.example/grp1/exmpl1.php">Example 1</a></li>
        <li class="submenu"><a href="https://www.example/grp1/exmpl2.php">Example 2</a></li>        


    </ul>
    </li>

   <li class="topmenu"> <a href="#">Grp 2</a>   
   <ul id="secondul">


       <li class="submenu"><a href="https://www.example/grp2/exmpl1.php">Example 1</a></li>
       <li class="submenu"><a href="https://www.example/grp2/exmpl2.php">Example 2</a></li>

   </ul>
   </li>

</ul>

</nav>
```

Now it happens, that sometimes, if I click f.e. on the first li in the `firstul` "Example 1" (which should lead to `https://www.example/grp1/exmpl1.php`) it loads the "Example 1" of the `secondul`and I dont find the mistake why. It appears completly random. Sometimes on the first click, sometimes after a few. Can somebody give me a hint why this happens?

Comment: Is there any javascript?

Comment: @CodeNewb Please show your complete code

Comment: Or make a fiddle where we can reproduce the bug.

Comment: The is nothing wrong with your code snippet. Maybe you have some JavaScript changing the href attribute?